# how to test the length of a value before make a update in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure that updates `table1` with some values of `table 2`. I need to check if one of the specific fields (age) has more than two digits.

```
table 2

code name      age
  1  jose       21
  2  peter      36
  3  jhon       50
  4  charlie   021
```

When the procedure is run, it throws an error because the age value of charlie field of `table1` has more than two digits.

I need a query to test the value before the UPDATE; if the age field has 3 digits, delete the first one and pass the 2 digits value. Example:

```
code name     age
   3 charlie  021
```

to:

```
code name     age
   3 charlie   21
```

And later make the procedure.

I used this query to know the length of the field

```
SELECT age, LENGTH(TRIM(table2.age)) FROM table2;

age    LENGTH(TRIM(table2.age))
 21     2
 36     2
 50     2
 021    3
```

Comment: Will it always be the right 2 characters?  You could use `right(age,2)`...  What about ages 100 and older?  I'd suggest storing these as integers and then you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: can u show your SP.it would be easy to correct then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use SUBSTRING('Sakila', -2) method to retrieve the last two digit with where length > 2.

SELECT CASE WHEN length(trim(age))>2 THEN SUBSTRING(age, -2) ELSE age END;

without any condition --

SELECT SUBSTR(age, -2) from table;

Comment: The function in Oracle is `substr` not `substring`.  I'm not sure the `CASE` statement does much-- why not call `substr` every time?  I doubt you gain any efficiency by computing the length every time rather than always taking the last two characters.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this ::

```
SELECT id, to_char(table1.age,'FM90') age FROM table1;
```

Note : The above query will work only if table1.age is appended with 0's on the left, for example :

021 or 0021 and so on.